# JS не находит свойство у CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется проблема. У меня сам код работает хорошо и исправно, но иногда бывает так, что при заходе/открытии/перезагрузки моей страницы JavaScript не может найти/различить свойство стиля css, он думает, что это должна быть переменная и выдает ошибку. Покажу на моем примере:

```
HTML
        <div id="block">
           <img src="image">
        </div>
```

```
JS
      block.style.display = 'block';
```

```
CSS

#block {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Я хочу присвоить стиль объекту block, а именно показать его на экране. Но иногда бывает, что js не различает, что это css объект и выдаёт ошибку: *Uncaught ReferenceError: block is not defined.*

После я обновляю страницу и все нормально.

**Самое главное, что это происходит не всегда, *а лишь иногда.***

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Как вы получаете элемент block, и в каком месте в коде он выполняется, сам этот блок вставляется динамически?

Comment: Получил уже ответ, спасибо. Он выполняется по центру, но почти сразу же, блок появляется не динамически.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно DOM не успевает прогрузиться в то время как код JS уже начал работу. Как минимум код можно выполнять дождавшись прогрузки DOM с помощью события  **[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // ВОТ ТУТ
});
```

Либо загружать скрипт для работы с атрибутом `defer` (если скрипт в отдельном файле)

```
<script defer src="https://javascript.info/article/script-async-defer/long.js?speed=1"></script>
        ^^^^
```

Атрибут `defer` сообщает браузеру, что он должен продолжать обрабатывать страницу и загружать скрипт в фоновом режиме, а затем запустить этот скрипт, когда DOM дерево будет полностью построено.

Comment: Спасибо, использовал второй способ, все работает.